# Как сделать дизайн spinner?

Tags: android, android-xml

Помогите, пожалуйста, мне нужно в spinner сделать размер текста побольше, поменять ему шрифт. Может быть какими то другими способами сделать его красивее. Прошу помощи!!!

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/SpinnerRecept"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            style="@style/spinners"
            android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/shapes"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView" />




<style name="spinners" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">
            @style/spinnerItemStyle
        </item>
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">
            @style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle
        </item>
    </style>
    <style name="spinnerItemStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">

        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
    </style>
    <style name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">

        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы сделать полностью кастомизируемый спиннер, вам нужно сделать для него адаптер, разметку одного элемента списка, и все это подключить вместе. Вот как это делать:

1. Сам спиннер:

   ```
   <Spinner
   android:id="@+id/simpleSpinner"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />
   ```
2. Разметку для одного item-a:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal">

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView"
       android:layout_width="50dp"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:padding="5dp"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" /><!--Make sure image is present in Drawable folder-->

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:text="Demo"
       android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. Адаптер для работы с данными:

   ```
   public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   Context context;
   int flags[];
   String[] countryNames;
   LayoutInflater inflter;

   public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, int[] flags, String[] countryNames) {
       this.context = applicationContext;
       this.flags = flags;
       this.countryNames = countryNames;
       inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return flags.length;
   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int i) {
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int i) {
       return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
       view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_items, null);
       ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
       TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
       icon.setImageResource(flags[i]);
       names.setText(countryNames[i]);
       return view;
   }
   ```

   }
4. Дальше в главной активности, вы подключаете сам спиннер и даете ему данные которые определены в конструкторе его адаптера:

   ```
   String[] countryNames={"India","China","Australia","Portugle","America","New Zealand"};
   int flags[] = {R.drawable.india, R.drawable.china, R.drawable.australia, R.drawable.portugle, R.drawable.america, R.drawable.new_zealand};

        ...
       Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.simpleSpinner);
       spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

       CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),flags,countryNames);
       spin.setAdapter(customAdapter);
   ```

вы можете сделать любую разметку с совершенно разными стилями. И дальше уже заполнять нужными вам данными. Этот [пример](https://abhiandroid.com/ui/custom-spinner-examples.html) я использую у себя в проекте, и он полностью рабочий, надеюсь и вам поможет.